# How to access value in a function as a global?

Tags: python, variables, global

Note: updated my original question

I have this code part in a script and need to access `co_create` value outside the module in the script.

```
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
  CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0

  def __init__(self):
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__()

  def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
        
        self.play = play
        extra_vars = ""
        vm = play.get_variable_manager()
        co_create = vm.extra_vars["co_create"]
```

Comment: There's no way that Ansible can set that variable until the module has been executed, and therefore a namespace exists in which the variable can even exist - but your top-level `print()` has already executed by that time.

Comment: The `global co_create` statement in the method indicates that `co_create` is defined at the **global** (i.e. module) level, but it's not (at least not in the code currently in your question. Where is this variable defined?

Comment: ultimately I want the value from "co_create = vm.extra_vars["co_create"]" retrieved inside the function to print with "print(co_create) outside of the function.

Comment: Jason, yes, I got your point, do you know how I should run the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have formatted `print(co_create)` on the final line in your snippet, it appears as the last line of the class definition for `CallbackModule`. When the class constructor get's to that point it is rightly complaining that the variable is not defined as there is neither a class-level variable in your example called `co_create` nor a reference to any global variable called `co_create` available at the module level. You have two options: (1.) define a module-level variable in the peer context to the class' definition, before the class is defined, called 'co_create' like:

```py
co_create = None

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play = ...
    obj = CallbackModule()
    obj.v2_playbook_on_play_start(play)
    print(co_create)  # no longer None
```

This will become the global variable you desire and should not require code change to any of your other code. (2.) similar to what you defined in the instance method `v2_playbook_on_play_start` access `co_create` with the global keyword at the class level before you print it. Option (1.) is preferred. You should try to avoid using global keyword unless you have to simply because it will require consistency across rest of module, hence more global keywords and more opportunities for error.

Comment: Ultimately, I want the value from "co_create = vm.extra_vars["co_create"]" but if I follow your suggestion, it prints None.

Comment: It will be None until you call the instance method `v2_playbook_on_play_start` to set it to a different value.

Comment: This design only works if the instance of the CallModule will be a singleton. The side effect of using a module-level global is all instances of this class will step on each others' feet, updating the value of the global var to reflect their context statefully.

Comment: To better encapsulate the the variable you might want to consider either putting the variable `co_create` as a class attribute just like `CALLBACK_VERSION` or assigning as an instance attribute during the /__init__ method.

Comment: its not possible to do that. you can't call an instance method for a class before the instance's type (the class itself) is defined.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, I think I see your points more clear.. and also wonder if it is chicken or egg first, as the play must come from the callback module (that takes "ansible playbook run") so I am not sure what I should put in [play = ...]

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer: it's not possible what I originally wanted to achieve with the ansible module: to get the variable retrieved from the module into the main block in the script, because the 'play' is called directly from ansible run, so no way I can specify it in the main block.
So I did make it work to push the return value from the main block to the module and the module to do the task instead.
Since skullgoblet1089 gave me a good direction, I will mark his answer good.